# Ornstein-Uhlenbeck MLE gives ridiculous results for different time spans?

Tags: r, maximum-likelihood, stochastic-processes, optimization

I am trying to do MLE estimation for a Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process as [described in this document](http://www.investmentscience.com/Content/howtoArticles/MLE_for_OR_mean_reverting.pdf)

My data consists of daily prices spanning two years. I'll include a plot of the data at the bottom of this question.

The problem I'm having is that depending on the scale I use for the time interval, I get ridiculously different results. For example, my data is equally spaced so if I use the procedure in that paper and set $t_i - t_{i-1}=1$ for all $i$, then I get results that make sense:

$$\theta=5, \mu=1.36, \sigma=0.234$$

However, this implies I'm looking at the process over the interval $[0,730]$. In reality, I would rather treat it as being over the interval $[0,2]$, so that each unit is $1$ year. Redoing this optimisation but with $t_i-t_{i-1}=\frac{1}{365}$ gives me results which are very clearly wrong! It ends up converging to $\theta=0$ which in turn gives $\mu=-33837.18$ and $\sigma = 0.1680891$.

$\sigma$ makes some sense, but a mean of $-33000$ is obviously ridiculous. Why is this the case? If it behaves as an Ornstein-Uhlenbeck on one scale, why does it become degenerate when I simply change the scale of time?

[image]

Comment: The likelihood function is invariant under a change of units, so I suspect a bug in the optimization algorithm. How do you optimize the likelihood?